# GraphQl Resolver Flow

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

```
type Query {
 content (query: Query!): Content!  
}

type Content {
  minions: Mold!  
  bosses: [FormattedNote]!  
}

type FormattedNote  {
  id: Int!  
  status: Int!  
  note: String!  
  content: String!      
 descendentsSums: [Int!]!  
}

type Mold {
  notes: [BossNoteMold]!  
}

type BossNoteMold {
  bossId: Int!  
  noteId: Int!  
  ordinal: Int!  
 owner: Int!  
}
```

I am aware that parent nodes are resolved first. Therefore in the above mentioned schema. `Content` field will be resolved first. Therefore my question is, will field `id` be resolved before field `notes` ? From what I understand `minions` and `bosses` are resolved asynchronously and therefor whether `id` or `notes` is resolved first is dependent on which parent is resolved first. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolver order will be:

1. `content` (query)
2. `Content.minions` and `Content.bosses` in parallel
   …
   `minions` should return a single `Mold` object. That object will then resolve its `notes` field which will return an array of `BossNoteMold` types

`bosses` should return an array of `FormattedNote` objects. Each one of those will then fire its field resolvers

There is little predictability in the order of operations after #1 as all these happen asynchronously and take various amounts of time depending on the complexity of each resolver.

The resolvers for the fields of a `FormattedNote` should have no dependency on the resolvers for a `Mold` type and vice-versa as neither are parents of the other.

Note: your model for the `BossNoteMold` type refers to IDs of related objects. It is more customary to refer to the related objects directly. Ex:

```
type BossNoteMold {
  boss: Boss!  
  note: Note!  
  ordinal: Int!  
  owner: User!  
}
```

In other words link to related objects by value instead of by reference (id). Referring by ID is a SQL practice that doesn't need to carry over to your GraphQL model.

Comment: Thank you! I actually figured it as I was writing this question. Nevertheless I designed my schema accordingly. I didn't know about "link to related objects by value " I will look into it!

Comment: By 'value' means that you should never see a *foreign key* in a type. Instead you would have a field with the foreign type itself.